# "No product catalog group supporting the url" error

Tags: umbraco-ucommerce

I'm upgrading an old Umbraco site (7.3.8) with uCommerce (Schema Version 148 - I'm unsure of the Version) to uCommerce 8.4.1.19353 (schema 203). And aside from a few hiccups, it's mostly gone okay. But I seem to have hit an error on the products.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
No product catalog group supporting the url "http://localhost:80/umbraco/ucommerce/catalog/editproduct.aspx?id=203&parentcategoryId=114" found.
```

When I create a new product in the category, I do not get the error though.

Anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the domain "localhost" on the store?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to do this as I was getting the same error on the store level. I've posted the answer to my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to do this as I was getting the same error on the store level.

I have however solved it by doing this.

- Comment out the lines 104 to 118 (the if(CanEditProduct()) block) in
  \Umbraco\ucommerce\Catalog\ProductReviewsList.ascx
- Going to the cms and set the correct domain on the store
- Uncommenting the above block